# Thunderbird for pop3 email account?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Can i use Thunderbird or for all my pop3 email accounts?
Know somebody something like Thunderbird, for free, for email account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird supports both POP3 and IMAP e-mail. Instructions on how to set up a POP3 account in Thunderbird can be found [here](http://www.freeemailtutorials.com/mozillaThunderbird/setupEmailAccount.cwd). It supports all mail services that provides POP3 interfaces. This includes services like GMail, Hotmail and MobileMe.

To configure Thunderbird for IMAP you can look [here](http://www.techiecorner.com/134/how-to-configure-thunderbird-for-imap-email/).

Comment: If they have a Hotmail account, they can use Windows Live Mail instead to get Hotmail emails. It also supports POP3 email accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Thunderbird to access multiple POP mailboxes from any e-mail provider.

However, If you are asking if you can have your e-mail box stored at Thunderbird (such as an address like yourName@mozillamessaging.com), no you can't. May I suggest Gmail if you are looking for a new e-mail provider? Gmail supports both POP and IMAP, and works with Thunderbird perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail now (Hotmail didn't use to support POP) supports POP which means Thunderbird can be used for Hotmail.